# Start date/time zone issue for data returned from crypto2 package

Tags: r, datetime, cryptocurrency

```
library(crypto2)
library(dplyr)
coins <- crypto_list(only_active=TRUE)

coin_hist_5_days <- crypto_history(coins, start_date=Sys.Date()-5)

coin_hist_5_days$timestamp %>% unique 

[1] "2024-02-01 23:59:59 IST" "2024-02-02 23:59:59 IST"
[3] "2024-02-03 23:59:59 IST" "2024-02-04 23:59:59 IST"
```

Why do I get 4 data points in the result? I would think I should have 5 data points.

```
> Sys.Date()-5
[1] "2024-01-31"
>
```

I think the Sys.Date() is being compared with `2024-01-31 23:59:59`

I am not 100% certain of how this comparison is being made. I could rephrase my query: How does Sys.Date() compare with a ***timestamp***. I think that is confusing the software.

Also, if I understand correctly all crypto currencies are quoted in `UTC time` ***and*** midnight is the time stamp for each crypto currency.

Why is it quoted in my local time zone `IST`?

Examining [the code of crypto_history() function](https://github.com/sstoeckl/crypto2/blob/master/R/crypto_history.R) I noticed:
that the UNIXstart has no "tz" option:

```
  UNIXstart <- format(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(start_date, format="%Y%m%d")),scientific = FALSE)
 
  UNIXend <- format(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(end_date, format="%Y%m%d", tz = "UTC")),scientific = FALSE)
```

Perhaps that is causing the defaulting of the output to my time zone which is IST ?

Answer (score 1):

`?coin_history` reveals that the `coin_history` function expects a `start_date` parameter in the following format:

> string Start date to retrieve data from, format 'yyyymmdd'

```r
library(crypto2)
library(dplyr)
coins <- crypto_list(only_active=TRUE)

coin_hist_5_days <- crypto_history(coins, start_date=format(Sys.Date()-5, '%Y%m%d'))

coin_hist_5_days$timestamp %>% unique
```

Should give you the result you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, changing the ***format*** does give me the result I am expecting. Can you please tell me why the ***timezone*** for crypto is IST when I think it should be UTC?

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the source code for the `crypto_history` function. My quick glance at it would indicate that the timezone for the timestamp field just defaults to the users one... but don't take my word for it, I didn't look very carefully.